# Why can't I find the Umbraco Forms Enum Namespace any more?

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco7

I've come across an issue in Umbraco where I was (once upon a time) able to use the `Umbraco.Forms.Core.Enums` namespace however, since I've checked my current code in and done a build ready for production, the compiler is failing to recognize it exists any more!

it's giving the standard error of
 `The type or namespace name 'Enums' does not exist in the namespace 'Umbraco.Forms.Core' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Could anyone point me in the right direction with this? I've tried updating Umbraco.core, umbraco itself and searching in the namespace to try and find this Enums type but I just can't find it!

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Because you named one class the same as a namespace.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be the case because when I do a find in files for the namespace in question it only appears in using statements?